# weld @Inject a interface

Tags: jboss-weld

i'm new to weld.
I'm setup a seam 3 project war packaged.
I want to discover picketlink security management and in order to test his various mamanger (after setup the database and entity classes) i've created a controller (TestAction class) so:

```
@Named("testAction")
@ConversationScoped
public  class TestAction implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Inject
  PersistenceManager persistenceManager;


  public void createUser() throws IdentityException
  {


    persistenceManager.createUser("TEST_USER");
  }
}
```

My env is jboss 6 final.

On startup i got:

```
WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [PersistenceManager] with qualifiers
[@Any] at enter injection point [[field] @Inject @Any
com.mycompany.myproject.action.TestAction.persistenceManager]
```

PersistenceManager is an interface with a concrete class with a parameter (IdentitySesionImpl)

How can i Inject PersistenceManager?
What is the meaning of WELD-001408?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand. do you want to use JPA persistence Manager or is it a class you created by your own ?

If it's a JPA persistence manager, you don't have to provide an implementation but to configure JPA in persistence.xml file.

If it's you interface and class, I encourage you to change their names beacause they are quite confusing. And you should check if your implementation is a valid CDI Bean : concrete class with no constructor or at least a default constructor without parameters.